# Query two random posts and make them inside carusel

Tags: jquery, wordpress, posts, jquery-post

I'd like to query random posts from a category and then display only two of them inside a carousel so if the slide changes there will be another two random posts displayed. Is it doable? I know that using only one post its easy but i cant figure it out how to do that.

Example of one fading:

```
fadeContent();    

function fadeContent() {
    $(".div-roles div:hidden:first-child").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
        fadeContent();
    });
}

<div class="div-roles">
    <div>Spinach</div>
    <div>Broccoli</div>
    <div>Carrots</div>
</div>
<div class="static-loader"></div>
```

My current posts query is like that:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
<div class="block">
    <div class="wrapper">        
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="text">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

With that js code above, i can query out all posts and make them fade, but i just simple cant work out how to do it with two posts.

One thought was to wrap two posts in one div but im not very familiar with PHP so my skills arent that good.

Thanks!

Comment: Dude, what on earth is the code in your question doing in respect of the actual question?!

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I edited first post with result i am having right now.

Comment: So, i have found a solution.
i have used two of the loops that i have up there and displayed them in random order. works like a charm.